# parsing a given path in c#

Tags: c#

I have a path "C:\Users\TestProject\TestProject.csproj

I want to get the path up until "C:\Users\TestProject

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 string dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(myPath);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string fullFilename= @"C:\Users\TestProject\TestProject.csproj";

string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullFilename);
```