# parse a path in c#

Tags: c#

i have this path

"Web References\myWebService\myWebService.wsdl"

how do i get the path up to "Web References\myWebService\"

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386258/parsing-a-given-path-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Path.GetDirectoryName`

Comment: She already knows that, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386258/parsing-a-given-path-in-c

Comment: @Henk, had no idea about the other question