# Regex match take a very long time to execute

Tags: c#, regex, performance

I wrote a regular expression that parses a file path into different group (DRIVE, DIR, FILE, EXTENSION).

```
^((?<DRIVE>[a-zA-Z]):\\)*((?<DIR>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(([a-zA-Z0-9_\s_\-\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)))\\)*(?<FILE>([a-zA-Z0-9_]+(([a-zA-Z0-9_\s_\-\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_]+))\.(?<EXTENSION>[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6})$))
```

I made a test in C#. When the path I want to test is correct. The result is very quick and this is what I wanted to expect.

```
string path = @"C:\Documents and Settings\jhr\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FileEncryptor\Dds.FileEncryptor\Dds.FileEncryptor.csproj";
```

=> OK

But when I try to test with a path that I know that will not match, like this :

```
string path = @"C:\Documents and Settings\jhr\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FileEncryptor\Dds.FileEncryptor\Dds.FileEncryptor?!??????";
```

=> BUG

The test freezes when I call this part of code

```
Match match = s_fileRegex.Match(path);
```

When i look into my Process Explorer, I see the process QTAgent32.exe hanging at 100% of my processor. What does it mean ?

Comment: Have you considered [parsing the path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386258/parsing-a-given-path-in-c) before validating?

Comment: Why are you not using the useful methods in the Path class? There is no need to use regex to extract this information.

Comment: RegEx really is the wrong way to go here. I still would like to know why this RegEx kills regexr.com :>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is called [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) and is due to the large number of ways that you regular expression can match the start of the string, which gives slow performance due to the backtracking regular expression engine in .NET.

I think you are using `*` too frequently in your regular expression. `*` does not mean "concatenate" - it means "0 or more times". For example there should not be a `*` here:

```
((?<DRIVE>[a-zA-Z]):\\)*
```

There should be at most one drive specification. You should use `?` instead here, or else no quantifier at all if you want the drive specification to be compulsory. Similarly there appear to be other places in your regular expression where the quantifier is incorrect.

Comment: good answer, tyvm :) (+1)
maybe you can put this link in your answer, it explains pretty good how this happens:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Answer (score 7):

Mark Byers is correct in that the reason for the problem is [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), however it's the last part that's causing the problem, not the bit that matches the drive letter.

For example, in

```
(?<FILE>
  ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+
    (
      ([a-zA-Z0-9_\s_\-\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)
    |
      ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)
    )\.
    (?<EXTENSION>[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6})
  $)
)
```

you can see that

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_\s_\-\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)
|
([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)
```

can match the same string in a number of different ways that will increase exponentially with the length of the filename.

When it happens that the extension part of the regex fails to match, the regex engine backtracks and tries a different permutation for the filename part, hoping that this enables the extension part to match - which of course it never will, but the regex engine can't figure that out. [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com), when asked to test the regex on the path you provided, aborts the match attempt after 1.000.000 iterations. The C# regex engine will plod on until it has exhausted all permutations, pinning your CPU at 100% during that time.

To fix this, it's generally necessary to avoid repetitions of repeated elements, to avoid alternations that match the same things, and possibly to enclose parts of the match in [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) that will not be backtracked into if a later part of the regex fails.

In your case however, it's better to use the right tools for the job, and those are the path manipulation functions of .NET.

Comment: Thank you for your very clearly response. You have right, I will use functions availables on .NET framework instead!

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use [`System.IO.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) functions?

- Drive: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getpathroot.aspx
- Directory: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx minus what is gotten for Drive
- Filename: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx
- Extension: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use the `FileInfo` and `Path` classes to obtain the info.

Should you choose to use a regex, 
then note that the regex doesn't match all legal filenames: There's a whole bunch of legal filename tokens missing from your regex.