# Visual Studio hangs searching for regex ^.*$

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

(To clarify, I'm talking about Ctrl-Shift-F search.  Current Document.)

I want to search for lines that don't contain a certain character, like '(', so I figure I need to include ^ and $ indicators to get the entire line.  But this just crashes the GUI.  Is there a way forward?

Lines without `(` should be handled by this:

```
^[^\(]*$
```

But this hangs, as does the simpler `"^.*$"`.

Maybe there's another way to find these lines?

EDIT: the proposed "duplicate" question is about C# RegEx class, completely utterly different from Visual Studio 2010 interactive regular expressions.

Comment: `^[^(]*$` is the right way to do what you want... can you give us how you're using it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex match take a very long time to execute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403512/regex-match-take-a-very-long-time-to-execute)

Comment: Duplicate, what may work better in your specific case: `^[^(]{1,}?$` This forces it to eat a character every time it does the comparison, and the lazy `?` stops it from eating more than 1 line at a time, which should prevent it exploding.

Comment: If you  want to match *lines*, use `^[^\r\n(]*$`, where `\r` and `\n` are excluded from `[^(]`

Comment: It's true that `^[^(]*$` will match any number of lines that don't contain `(`, but why should that cause the editor to hang?  Or `^.*$`, which matches any one line?  VS 2010 still uses that old, bizarre regex flavor, but these particular regexes mean just what you expect them to; I don't see why they should cause a problem.

Comment: Alan Moore.  I agree that it doesn't make sense.  But nevertheless if I do enter that expression in the search box and click Find All, I must kill and restart Visual Studio.  The problem doesn't exist if I skip the ^ or $, but that won't give me a valid search result.

Comment: Wiktor, that seems to be the answer.  I was under the false impression that search would restrict itself to single lines by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match lines, use `^[^\r\n(]*$`, where `\r` and `\n` are excluded from `[^(]` – Wiktor Stribiżew Jun 27 at 19:36

This comment is indeed the answer.  Apparently old Visual Studio searches could span multiple lines, and `^.*$` thus means start at the beginning of the line, go forward any number of characters ***up to the end of the document***, then stop at the end of a line.  These characters can include any number of newlines.

VS apparently didn't efficiently implement this query and hangs interminably.

W.S.'s proposal explicitly excludes newlines from the search parameters, thereby forcing only a single line.

Visual Studio 2012 changes to more conventional regular expression search which limits results to within single lines, so ^.*$ will just fetch all the lines of a document one by one.